Problem to re-add faulty device to raid5 with mdadm
I have the situation as follows:
$ cat /proc/mdstat
md125 : inactive sdb4[4] sda4[1](F) sdc4[3](F)
470937607 blocks super 1.2

then in details:
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md125  
/dev/md125:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Jul 12 13:52:54 2022
        Raid Level : raid5
     Used Dev Size : 470937600 (449.12 GiB 482.24 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sat Jul 27 14:23:11 2024
             State : active, FAILED, Not Started 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 2
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : unknown

              Name : localhost-l:0
              UUID : a672e13c:1023c9f3:798a0153:3b76b4c1
            Events : 89231

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       -       0        0        1      removed
       -       0        0        2      removed

       -       8       36        -      faulty   /dev/sdc4
       -       8       20        0      sync   /dev/sdb4
       -       8        4        -      faulty   /dev/sda4

but:
$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sda4
/dev/sda4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : a672e13c:e023c9f3:d98a0153:3b76b4cb
           Name : localhost-live:0
  Creation Time : Tue Jul 12 13:52:54 2022
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 941875215 sectors (449.12 GiB 482.24 GB)
     Array Size : 941875200 KiB (898.24 GiB 964.48 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 941875200 sectors (449.12 GiB 482.24 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=15 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 558f62a0:3014c753:f44e1d53:0dd51dfd

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sat Jul 27 00:54:21 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : e534cbe1 - correct
         Events : 89230

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

Same for sdc4, the State is clean. What is more Events values are really close to each other:
$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sd[abc]4 | grep Events
         Events : 89230
         Events : 89231
         Events : 89230

Based on above results and information provided on other stackexchange questions and discussions and man page of mdadm I found that I just can use '--re-add faulty' option. But when tried:
$ sudo mdadm /dev/md125 --re-add faulty
mdadm: Cannot open 8:4: Permission denied

Now I do not know which resource is denied when journalctl says nothing about it.
